# Selecting two values from the same table but under different conditions

Tags: query, reporting

I want to grab a value from a table into two different columns for different values from the same table. Use this query as an example (notice how the select is on the same table aliased as 2 different tables):

```
SELECT a.myVal, b.myVal 
FROM MyTable a, MyTable b
WHERE 
  a.otherVal = 100 AND
  b.otherVal = 200 AND
  a.id = b.id
```

When I run a relatively simple query like this on my dataset, it works - it just takes a long time. Is there a better/smarter way of writing this query?

Answer (score 10):

For readability I would rewrite the query using the more modern join syntax.  This will clearly separate your join conditions from your filters.

```
select a.myVal,
       b.myVal
  from MyTable a
  join MyTable b on b.id = a.id
where a.OtherVal = 100
  and b.Otherval = 200
```

For performance, ensure you have proper indexes.  In this limited example, ideally you would have a clustered index on ID and a non-clustered index on OtherVal.

After looking at your query, however, I cannot tell just what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: to add to @datagod: `SELECT a.column, b.column FROM table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.column=x AND b.column=y` could be another way to avoid using `JOIN` (when not necessary).

Comment: @wolfram77, that is still a join.

Answer (score 4):

You could use grouping and conditional aggregating, like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE OtherVal WHEN 100 THEN MyVal END) AS MyVal1,
  MAX(CASE OtherVal WHEN 200 THEN MyVal END) AS MyVal2
FROM MyTable
WHERE OtherVal IN (100, 200)
GROUP BY
  id
;
```